# Sha256 hash with 1000 iterations in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, hash, sha256

I am trying to generate sha256 hash with 1000 iterations in my asp.net core 2.0 project via below code but it's not generating correctly.
Can anyone please help me.

**Updated Code:**

```
public static string CreateSHA256HashWithIteration(string Password, int Iterations = 1000)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
    {
        Password = CreateSHA256Hash(Password);
    }
    return Password;
}
public static string CreateSHA256Hash(string Password)
{
    try
    {
        using (SHA256 mySHA256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] bytArr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Password);
            byte[] hashValue = mySHA256.ComputeHash(bytArr);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Exception";
    }

}
```

**Old Approach**

```
public static string CreateSHAHash(string Password, int iterations=1000)
{
    try
    {
        // generate a 128-bit salt using a cryptographically strong random sequence of nonzero values
        byte[] salArr = new byte[128 / 8];
        using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rngCsp.GetNonZeroBytes(salArr);
        }

        byte[] bytArr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Password);
        //byte[] salArr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Salt);
        // System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed HashTool = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();
        HashAlgorithm sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            //String str = ToHex(bytArr) + ToHex(salArr);
            string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytArr) + Convert.ToBase64String(salArr);
            bytArr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
            //bytArr = HashTool.ComputeHash(bytArr);
            bytArr = sha.ComputeHash(bytArr);

        }
        string hexEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(bytArr);
        return hexEncoded;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Exception";
    }

}
```

Comment: What **exactly** does "not generating correctly" mean?

Comment: I am calling some external APIs which needs password to be generated SHA 256 hashed with 1000 iterations. I'm applying above code and API says incorrect password although password is correct which I verified with vendor. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: And you've verified that this is the approach you should be using? Not just hashing 1000 times but converting to base64, appending salt, then encoding for utf8 and then computing hash?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Didn't get the issue in above code? Can you highlight or correct it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I updated the code. Is this the right approach?

Comment: I don't know if this is the right approach, it needs to match what the owners of the servers are doing.